# Woocommerce discount if has certain attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, commerce

Every product in my database has an "pa_producator" attribute, and i want the following thing:
When pa_producator is equal to "Bosch", apply an 10% discount on that product only, not on the whole cart. Is this possible? Until now i have only the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_producer');
function discount_producer( ) {
global $woocommerce;
$test = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($test as $product) {
  $test = get_the_terms( $product['product_id'], 'pa_producator');
  $producator = $test[0]->name;
}
}
```

How can i apply discount for those products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to update values before any output. So it would apply to all places where Cart is used.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'check_cart_items', 99, 1);
```

Search for this action. This is called right after Cart is created. Then you can adjust price for each item in cart. Same way you already are trying.

```
public function check_cart_items($cart) {
    foreach ( $cart->cart_contents as $key => $product ) {
        // find attribute for current product
        // .. do stuff
        $cart->cart_contents[ $key ]['data']->price = $new_price;
        $cart->cart_contents[ $key ]['data']->regular_price = $price;
        $cart->cart_contents[ $key ]['data']->sale_price = $price;
    }
}
```